# Django group_by argument depending on order_by

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I'm struggling (again) with Django's annotate functionality where the actual SQL query is quite clear to me.

**Goal:**

I want to get the number of users with a certain let's say `status` (it could be just any column of the model).

**Approach(es):**

1) `User.objects.values('status').annotate(count=Count('*'))`

This results into the following SQL query

```sql
SELECT users_user.status, COUNT(*) as count
FROM users_user
GROUP BY users_user.id
ORDER BY usser_user.id ASC
```

However, this will give me a queryset of all users each "annotated" with the count value. This is kind of the behaviour I would have expected.

2)  `User.objects.values('status').annotate(count=Count('*')).order_by()`

This results into the following SQL query

```sql
SELECT users_user.status, COUNT(*) as count
FROM users_user
GROUP BY users_user.status
```

No `ORDER BY`, and now the `GROUP BY` argument is the `status` column. This is not what I expected, but **the result I was looking for**.

**Question**:
Why does Django's `order_by()` without any argument affect the SQL `GROUP BY` argument? (Or broader, why does the second approach "work"?)

*Some details*:

- django 2.2.9
- postgres 9.4

Comment: What about `User.objects.values('status').annotate(count=Count('*')).order_by('status')`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it only changes the order, but except of that it yields the same result as `order_by()`

Comment: `User.objects.all().values('status').annotate(total=Count('status')).order_by('total')`  - does that do what you want?

Comment: The 2) approach already does what I want. Sorry, if I wasn't clear about that in my question. I don't understand why it does what I expected. That's what I tried to say in the "Question" part.

Comment: Are you sure the first approach turns into the query you wrote? This query looks strange: there is no field `status` in `GROUP BY` clause but it is in `SELECT` statement. I guess it must raise an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by)

*Fields that are mentioned in the order_by() part of a queryset (or which are used in the default ordering on a model) are used when selecting the output data, even if they are not otherwise specified in the values() call.*